Integrated Graphl QL query does not return child items
I am trying to fetch the child items in one of my JSS Projects from context item. Have written the below query but it throws error in the layout service request.
Query -
query CarouselQuery($contextItem: String!) {
  FetchChild: item(path: $contextItem) {
    child {
        id
        name
     }
   }
}

Any idea what can be the possible issue?

Child items can be accessed using the children field.
Here is how you can modify your query to fetch child items:
query CarouselQuery($contextItem: String!) {
  item(path: $contextItem) {
    children {
      results {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}

In this modified query:
children is used to access child items.
results is used to iterate over the list of child items.
Hope this helps!

Thanks this is working. @Nikita

Can you try running below query from the Integrated GraphQL.
query CarouselQuery($contextItem: String!) {
  FetchChild: item(path: $contextItem) {
    children {
        results{
         id
         name
       }
     }
   }
}

This will return the child item details of the context item using the children property and then iterating over it using the results property.
Hope this helps!!!
